# Procedimiento almacenado con UPDATE

Tags: oracle-11g

Tengo este procedimiento donde quiero que le sume 1 al campo numerico "CONSECUTIVO" pero me da error como podria hacerlo?

El error dice: Error de sintaxis, se esperaba un NAME o EXPR

```
create or replace PROCEDURE get_secuencia(consec OUT NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
   consec:= UPDATE EQUIVALENTES_CONSECUTIVO SET CONSECUTIVO = CONSECUTIVO + 1;       
END;
```

Comment: No pusiste el **Where**

Comment: que error te da ?

Comment: error de sintaxis en el UPDATE

Comment: No veo el WHERE!!

Comment: igual asi no tenga el where no deberia afectar, deberia actualizar todos los registros, por otro la pon el error que te da para saber por donde va el error

Comment: El error dice: Error de sintaxis, se esperaba un NAME o EXPR

Comment: quitale los ":" a `consec=` y encierra entre parentesis la operacion `(CONSECUTIVO + 1)`

Comment: Creo que lo que estas queriendo hacer es una aberración por eso te da error, porque quieres setear un campo con el valor del mismo campo, pero la forma en que lo estas haciendo no es la correcta deberias de ser algo así `UPDATE EQUIVALENTES_CONSECUTIVO SET CONSECUTIVO = (SELECT CONSECUTIVO FROM EQUIVALENTES_CONSECUTIVO WHERE (alguna condicion que te regrese el que tu quieras de lo contrario te va a traer una colección) )+ 1;`

Comment: Creo que asi te da un error @M.Gress por especificacion duplicada :)

Comment: Si da error, como hacer un update normal?

Comment: @alanfcm te dio la respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intentalo asi:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE get_secuencia(consec OUT NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE EQUIVALENTES_CONSECUTIVO SET CONSECUTIVO = CONSECUTIVO + 1;   
   SELECT CONSECUTIVO INTO consec FROM EQUIVALENTES_CONSECUTIVO;    
END;
```